# trying to use struct on aheader file and includeed it in the main and the class file

Tags: c++, class, struct

i used struct in aheader file and i included it in the main.cpp and in the class.h and it's cpp but i got some errors the errors are

> Error  1   error C2511: 'void fkingatm::test1(user [])' : overloaded member function not found in 'fkingatm'
>
> Error  2   error C3861: 'test1': identifier not found
>
> Error  3   IntelliSense: identifier "test1" is undefined

**STRUCT_HEADER.h**

```
#ifndef STRUCT_HEADER
#define STRUCT_HEADER
struct user {
    int arr[10];
};
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "STRUCTHEADER.h"
int main(){
    user users[10];
     test1(users);
```

**fkingatm.h (the class file)**

```
#ifndef FKINGATM_H
#define FKINGATM_H
#include "STRUCTHEADER.h"
class fkingatm
{
public:
    void test1(user);
};
#endif
```

**fkingatm.cpp**

```
#include "fkingatm.h"
void fkingatm::test1(user users[10]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cin >> users[0].arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout<< users[0].arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your declaration `void test1(user);` does not match your implementation `void fkingatm::test1(user users[10]){`. The former has one parameter of type `user` the latter one of type `user[]`. (Do you see the difference?) Btw. you know that function array parameters decay to pointers, don't you?

Comment: I am confused by "i used struct in aheader file and i declared it in the main.cpp", I'd expect it the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Your main.cpp evaluates as: (Assuming STRUCT_HEADER isn't #defined before STRUCT_HEADER.h and that you just misspelled your STRUCTHEADER.h in this question )

```
struct user {
    int arr[10];
};

int main(){
    user users[10];
     test1(users);
```

Since #include only pastes whatever the contents of the file you put in front of it on the line it's written on. It won't see your definition of test1.

You should try:

```
#include "fkingatm.h"
#include "STRUCTHEADER.h"


int main(){
    user users[10];
    fkingatm f;
    f.test1(users);
    return 0; 
}
```

Now, that solves the 2nd and 3rd Error you had. For the 1st error, you will need to edit the declaration of your void

```
void test1(user);
```

to

```
void test1(user[10]);
```

edit:
That is because you're using your test1(user user[10]) as one that takes a user[10] and not a user. And user[10] is different type and data on its own. Different data in the sense that user[10] is actually a pointer(a number that represents a memory address) and user is a class/struct(Which is only a namespace and doesn't really have an exact physical representation in memory).